# How to find the buffer number of a :terminal?

Tags: terminal-buffer

I can see that I've got a terminal buffer open by running `:ls R` which finds all buffers with a running terminal job, but I don't know how to capture just the buffer number.

The closest I can get is `echo bufnr("cmd.exe")` because the buffer name has the command the terminal is using. This isn't crossplatform though.

`bufnr("R")` doesn't seem to search the flags the same was `:ls R` does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. By `:h 'buftype'`

   ```
   echo filter(map(getbufinfo(), 'v:val.bufnr'), 'getbufvar(v:val, "&buftype") is# "terminal"')
   ```
2. By `:h getwininfo()`

   ```
    echo uniq(map(filter(getwininfo(), 'v:val.terminal'), 'v:val.bufnr'))
   ```

Comment: Thanks for these! Makes sense there isn't a builtin way to get a terminal buffer's number directly given how you can have so many

Comment: Which one would be faster? just curious...